# Sending data through context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have an android application where the screen is divided into horizontal layouts, in which data is shown. When the user presses one of those layouts and holds for a bit, I need the application to open a context menu, through which I need to send the data that is shown in the layout, to another activity. How do I send the data through a context menu? Thank you in advance for any help given

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```
void writeMyInt(int value) {
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myState", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
        .edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putInt("myInt", state);
    editor.commit();
}

int getMyInt() {
    return getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myState",
            MODE_MULTI_PROCESS).getInt("myInt", 0);
}
```